# Parent component scoped style overriding child component scoped style

Tags: vue.js

I have 2 components in Vue. In the main component I apply a class called `elDiv` that has yellow background color. The secondary component uses a class also called `elDiv` that has blue background color. Both components have their styles scoped however the color rendered for both components is yellow when the parent component should be yellow and the child blue

**Parent**

```
<template>
  <div class="elDiv">
    FICHA
    <BotonLlamada />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BotonLlamada from "./components/BotonLlamada.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    BotonLlamada,
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.elDiv {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
  <button class="elDiv">BOTON</button>HELLO
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "BotonLlamada",
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.elDiv {
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
```

[image]

However, if in the second component I write anything after the button tag the styles are displayed correctly. For example:

```html
<button class="elDiv">BOTON</button>HELLO
```

[image]

I don't really understand what could be happening

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is explained in the documentation [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#child-component-root-elements)

> With `scoped`, the parent component's styles will not leak into child components. However, **a child component's root node will be affected by both the parent's scoped CSS and the child's scoped CSS**. This is by design so that the parent can style the child root element for layout purposes.

You can see this in action when inspecting the DOM.

```html
<div data-v-7ba5bd90 class="elDiv"> 
  FICHA 
  <button data-v-bb07bdb6 data-v-7ba5bd90 class="elDiv">BOTON</button>
</div>
```

Notice the data attribute applied to the parent, `data-v-7ba5bd90`, is also on the root child node. Due to the classnames being **exactly** the same it so happens from specificity that the CSS for `.elDiv[data-v-7ba5bd90]` (parent style) overrides `.elDiv[data-v-bb07bdb6]` (child style).

The reason adding anything after the button, e.g. `<button class="elDiv">BOTON</button>HELLO`, fixes the issue is because the text `HELLO` acts as a second root node.  Vue does not apply fallthrough attributes when more than one root node exists.

A better option would be to use different classnames OR surround the child component's button element in a `<span>`.

```html
<span>
  <button class="elDiv">BOTON</button>
</span>
```

You should notice now in the DOM that the span receives the fallthrough data attribute, meaning the button's CSS is not overridden

```html
<div data-v-7ba5bd90 class="elDiv"> 
  FICHA 
  <span data-v-bb07bdb6 data-v-7ba5bd90>
    <button data-v-bb07bdb6 class="elDiv">BOTON</button>
  </span>
</div>
```